# Minimal polynomial of extension of degree 2 over a finite field with characteristic 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I'm struggling to solve the following question.

> Let $F$ be a finite field with characteristic 2 and $L/F$ be a finite extension with $[L:F]=2$.  Prove that there exists $\alpha\in L$ such that $L = F(\alpha) $ and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ , $\text {Irr}_F \alpha(x) = x^2-x-a$ for some $a\in F$

My attempt:

Let $\alpha\in L\text \F$, then $F\subset F(\alpha) \subset L$ is a tower, so we have $2 = [L:F] = [L:F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F]$.
Because $\alpha\notin F$, $[F(\alpha):F]=2$ and $[L:F(\alpha)]=1$.

So we get $L=F(\alpha)$.

Let $p_\alpha(x) = \text{Irr}_F\alpha(x)$.

Note that deg $(p_\alpha(x)) = [F:F(\alpha)] = 2$ . So we can assume that $p_\alpha(x) = x^2+bx+a \in F[x]$, here $a\in F, b\in F.$

Then, I want to show that there exists $\alpha \in L\text\F$ such that $b=1$.

First, I'm trying to find  $\alpha$  such that b $\neq 0$:

Observe that if  $\alpha^2\in F$, then the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ will be $x^2-\alpha^2$.

So I want to find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2\notin F$, if such $\alpha$ exists, then $b\neq 0$.

But I have no ideal about how to prove the existence of this $\alpha$.

And here comes another problem: If we can find $\alpha\in L\text\\F$ satisfy the condition above, how can we say that $b=1$ ?

So I would like to know that my thoughts are correct or not, and want to solve this question in elementary method (without Galois Theory).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have $b=0$.

If $|K|=2^n$ then $a=a^{2^n}$ for every $a\in K$. If $a=0$ this is trivial. Otherwise $a$ belongs to the group $(K^*,\cdot )$ of order $2^n-1$ so, by Lagrange's theorem, $a^{2^n-1}=1$. We multiply this relation by $a$ and we get $a^{2^n}=a$.

Suppose now that $b=0$ so $p_\alpha (x)=x^2+a$. Since $a=a^{2^n}=(a^{2^{n-1}})^2$ and we are in characteristic $2$, we get $p_\alpha (x)=x^2+(a^{2^{n-1}})^2=(x+a^{2^{n-1}})^2$. But this is impossible, since $p_\alpha$ is irreducible.

Hence $b\neq 0$. When we divide the relation $\alpha^2+b\alpha +a=0$ by $b^2$ we get $(\alpha/b)^2+\alpha/b+a/b^2=0$ so $p_{\alpha/b}(x)=x^2+x+a/b^2=x^2-x-a/b^2$, which is what you want.

BTW you have a more general result. If $F$ is finite of characteristic $p$ and $[L:F]=p$ then $L=F(\alpha )$ for some $\alpha$ whose minimal polynomial over $F$ is of the form $x^p-x-a$ for some $a\in F$. But for this you need some Galois theory in positive characteristic. Look for Artin-Schreier extensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's what I want to know and clear my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomials $p_a(x)=x^2-x-a$ for $a\in F$.

Observe that for $a\neq b$, both in $F$, the roots of $p_a$ and $p_b$ are disjoint. This is because a common root $r$ implies $r^2-r-a=0=r^2-r-b$, from where $a=b$ follows.

Also, for a given $a\in F$, the two roots, $r_1$ and $r_2$, of $p_a$ satisfy $r_1+r_2=1$. If they there equal, then $0=2r_1=1$.

If $p_a$ were reducible for all $a\in F$, then the total number of the roots of these polynomials would would be $2|F|$ different elements of $F$.

Therefore, at least one of those polynomials $p_a$ is irreducible over $F$.

Then $F[x]/(p_a)$ is a finite field of characteristic $2$ with the same cardinality as $L$.